# Googleplay - Unsupported Device compatibility

Tags: android, google-play

I created a simple app and I just uploaded my apk. I noticed there are about 100 devices that are unsupported.

My manifest doesn't request any permission. Any ideas on what is causing this or how I can fix it?

```
<code>
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".asdfActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/CustomNoTitle" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.asdf" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".asdf2Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/CustomNoTitle" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.asdf2" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".asdf3Activity"
            android:theme="@style/CustomNoTitle" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.asdf3" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".asdf4Activity"
            android:theme="@style/CustomNoTitle" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.asdf4" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
 </code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a trade-off.There are always some devices your app can not be fully compatible.They are some of old-fashion ,out of production devices.When you want to be compatible with most of devices ,some of high-end devices with higher system os version and features you can not support.

[image]

Your app don't support 100 devices.However there are more than 8000 devices you can support.I think that focus on the majorities and spend more on improving experience for them will be more effective.

Maybe my answer can not solve your question directly.Hope it can make you no longer confused.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but I suppose there's nothing I can do besides release 2 versions to try to support different devices. I'm not too familiar with the googleplay process. Will people with unsupported devices be able to purchase the app if it's unsupported? I don't want to run into the headache of them buying it and complaining that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change baseline android:minSdkVersion="4" to android:minSdkVersion="8" and see if it's working.

if not than add following tags as per your requirement.

e.g.

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

and

```
<compatible-screens>
<screen android:screenSize=["small" | "normal" | "large" | "xlarge"]
        android:screenDensity=["ldpi" | "mdpi" | "hdpi" | "xhdpi"] />
...
</compatible-screens>
```

Ref. links :

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html
```

Comment: I originally had it at minsdk 8, but I lowered it to 4 and it made it compatible to more for some reason. I tried adding those 2 sections that you included; however, it's giving me 2 different warning. 

"attribute xlargeScreen is only used in api9"
"attribute screensize is only used in api9"

I tried to raise my minsdk to 9, and it raises the unsupported device to like 1000 from 100 previously.